# Web Service SOAP server was unable to process request

Tags: java, soap, web, service, glassfish

Hi I'm develping a web app in Java for a local bank and they have a SOAP Web Service that my app consumes. The app is deployed on GlassFish 3.1.2 and the web service was generated on .Net (I don't know the specifics, I'm new to the project) and everything is connected through a peer to peer VPN.

Now the issue I have is when I try to log in I get an EJBException:

> javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
>   Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Changes to this object and its sub-objects have been disabled (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8011042A) Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.

Now I'm trying to determine what exactly is the problem with the web service, or even better what should the guys at the bank check to determine what's wrong.

If anyone knows or has some ideas on what we should check please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be server problem. Send them exactly time stamp of request and all the request details, and they will probably guide you to the problem

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i tried that already and they're lost, do you by any chance might know why we are getting this exception? They told me that they added a security layer to the web service, I don't know what exactly they added, since we've been having this problem for over a month and they told me about this "layer" two days ago, is it possible that the so called security layer is blocking the request somehow??

Comment: it's really hard to tell anything without seeing the logs and these guys on server they are only one who can see logs, so you should point all your questions to them, not here :)